# How to structure a package during development?

Tags: go, github, testing

I would like to publish a package at `github.com/mylogin/mypackage`. In order to develop it, I created the following file structure

```
mypackage/
├─ mypackage.go
├─ go.mod  // used to be mypackage.mod by mistake
├─ tests/
│  ├─ firsttest_test.go
│  ├─ secondtest_test.go
```

`mypackage.go` will have one function (`mypackage(...)`)

<del>`mypackage.mod`</del> `go.mod` is currently

```
module github.com/mylogin/mypackage

go 1.17
```

My question: when writing tests, I need to import `mypackage`:

- on the one hand I cannot import `github.com/mylogin/mypackage` because it is not there yet
- on the other hand I should however import `github.com/mylogin/mypackage` because it is ultimately the way for others (or Actions) to replicate the tests

How can I get off this contradiction? What should be the proper layout of my files?

Comment: Do not put test in a separate folder. Read How to Write Go Code and stick to it. Take a look at how the stdlib does it and how other modules on github do it.

Comment: `mypackage.mod` is meaningless. Go will ignore it. You probably want `go.mod`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `mypackage.mod` is currently

The file must be called `go.mod`.  Any other name will be ignored by the Go toolchain.

> - on the one hand I cannot import `github.com/mylogin/mypackage` because it is not there yet

That's not actually relevant.  If you have a `go.mod` file (see above note about correcting the filename), Go knows to consider this first, before making network requests.  That means that it will find the `go.mod` at the top level of your project, and realize that your current project is that module, and use itself.

Comment: Of course I meant `go.mod`, sorry. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 2):

> on the one hand I cannot import `github.com/mylogin/mypackage` because it is not there yet

You *can* `import "github.com/mylogin/mypackage"`, because it is a package in the same module.

If that isn't working for some reason, there may be a typo either in the `module` directive in your `go.mod` file or in the `import` statement in the `_test.go` file.

---

That said, typically the tests for `github.com/mylogin/mypackage` would be located in the same directory as `mypackage` itself:

```
mypackage/
├─ go.mod
├─ mypackage.go
├─ firsttest_test.go
├─ secondtest_test.go
```

If you want to test the package's API from the perspective of an outside user, you can have the `_test.go` file declare `package mypackage_test` instead of `package mypackage`.

(See [`go help test`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Test_packages) for more detail.)